# Linux bash script: share variable among terminal windows

Tags: linux, bash, var

If I do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=KGDB -x bash -c 'VAR1=$(tty); 
echo $VAR1; bash'
echo $VAR1
```

How can I get the last line from this script to work? I.e., be able to access the value of $VAR1 (stored on the new terminal window) from the original one? Currently, while the first echo is working, the last one only outputs an empty line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that you can't share the variable. There's no shared channel for that.

You can write it to a file/pipe/etc. and then read from it though.

Something like the following should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

if _file=$(mktemp -q); then
    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=KGDB -x bash -c 'VAR1=$(tty); echo "$VAR1"; declare -p VAR1 > '\'"$_file"\''; bash'
    cat "$_file"
    . "$_file"
    echo "$VAR1"
fi
```

Comment: The slightly longer version is: you can by passing it into a temp var by `echo -n "\$VAR=$VAR" > /tmp/myvar.tmp` and source it in the other terminal by doing `source /tmp/myvar.tmp`

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Indeed, that's one method of doing what I suggest and using a file. Though I would use `declare -p VAR > some_temp_file_made_securely_with_mktemp` instead to avoid a number of issues.

Comment: @EthanReisner: It was an addition, no contradiction. ;) Maybe sth like `FILE=$(mktemp 2>&1) declare -p FOO > $FILE && echo $FILE` to get the file we have redirected to? ;)

Comment: Can't echo from inside the terminal shell (we won't see it) so file creation needs to be done outside. And I'd probably use `mktemp -qt` and check for errors from `mktemp` but yeah.

Comment: ? Works as shown... ;) And `mktemp -t` is deprecated since... erm... half a decade now? ;) Checked for coreutils 6.9...

Comment: All my day-to-day work in on CentOS 5 which is also at least that old so ok. =) And I'm not sure how you could get output to the current window from an echo inside a shell run by `gnome-terminal` presumably in its new window (especially once `tty` returns a meaningful new value) but I suppose maybe that's possible for things being run via `-x` that way.

Comment: No Gnome. ssh connection to CentOS 6.5 via OSX (to make double sure). Works on both.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I don't understand. My comment was specifically about using `echo` *inside* the shell spawned by `gnome-terminal` and how its output will not make it to the shell/script that spawned `g-t`. If you want that `FILE` variable available in the original script you can't do that work *inside* `g-t` is what I was saying.

Comment: Thank you all. What a great discussion! This is really valuable information. Accepted.